# find and replace using regex in my url

Tags: php, regex

find

```
[video=youtube;RrI-3vt5VnE]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrI-3vt5VnE[/video]
```

replace with

```
[MEDIA=youtube]RrI-3vt5VnE[/MEDIA]
```

like wise

Comment: like wise tried anything?

Comment: i mean my String will be in this pattern  [video=youtube;RrI-3vt5VnE]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrI-3vt5VnE[/video]   and i have to replace with [MEDIA=youtube]RrI-3vt5VnE[/MEDIA]   using regular expression in php

Comment: @JunedAnsari: Please update the question with **expected output**. I guess you are not speaking about https://regex101.com/r/sM6tK3/1 ? Or is it what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) like this:

```
$strData = 'jdlsgvb345454kasjvb [video=youtube;RrI-3vt5VnE]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrI-3vt5VnE[/video]vsdkjgvhs4533davlnasdjkvb';
    //random data containing one matched string

$outputData = preg_replace("#\[video=youtube;([^\]]+)[^\[]+\[/video\]#",
   '[MEDIA=youtube]$1[/MEDIA]', $strData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
var str = '[video=youtube;RrI-3vt5VnE]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrI-3vt5VnE[/video]';

var pattern = /\[video=youtube;([^\]]+)\].*\[\/video\]/;

var output = str.replace(pattern,'[MEDIA=youtube]$1[/MEDIA]');
```

Jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/samirkumardas/yaqsr7tu/